# TortoiseHG/Mercurial Project Statistics and Reports

Tags: mercurial, report, tortoisehg, bitbucket

I've been working for a couple months on cleaning up the backend of a system I'm working on. The previous code was awful so I've been refactoring and rewriting to get the code to a state where I can better add and improve functionality. I want to be able to quantify the work I've done for the client so he can get a sense of how much work has been done. So, I want to run some reports showing things like: number of lines removed, added, changed. I've used TortoiseHG/Mercurial all along and also have pushed the code up to bigbucket.

What's the best way to generate these types of statistics from TortoiseHG/Mercurial or BitBucket?

Answer (score 14):

- [Churn](http://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChurnExtension) extension
- [Activity](http://labs.freehackers.org/projects/hgactivity) extension
- [Chart](https://bitbucket.org/mg/hgchart/wiki/Home) extension
- [HG-chart](https://bitbucket.org/Ry4an/hg-chart-extension/wiki/Home) extension

---

* [HGstats](http://sphinx.net.ru/hg/hgstats/), when sphinx.net.ru will be returned back in Net

Comment: So I see that I can enable the Churn extension through TortoiseHG Settings-> Global Settings -> Extensions. Since it's the only one of your list that's directly available it probably makes sense to try to use it. But I'm not finding any info on using it. I'm guessing I could probably do it through the command line but since I'm expecting visual information, seems like there should be a better way through TortoiseHG.

Comment: I ran churn through the command line (go to the repository directory and then run "HG Churn") and it returned an ASCII based "chart" of changes per user. Was really disappointed. Really wanted something more over time... Looked at Activity and HG-chart but they seem very difficult to install on Windows because the charting library is difficult to get setup.

Comment: The chart extension was last updated over 2 years ago. So I'm guessing it's not compatible with Mercurial 2.x.

Comment: @EfficionDave: "Over time" is available with `hg churn` using arguments. Did you remember to check out `hg help churn`? Try this, for changes grouped by date: `hg churn -f "%Y-%m-%d" -s`.